# To get data from calendar in OnDestroy or OnPause

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar, onpause, ondestroy

I have this code:

```
namespace TestB
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestB", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Java.Util.Calendar calendar;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            try
            {
                calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
                calendar.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            if (calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay) == 13 && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute) == 33)
                Toast.MakeText(this, calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay).ToString() + " " + calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute).ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            if (calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay) == 13 && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute) == 33)
                Toast.MakeText(this, calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay).ToString() + " " + calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute).ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

When the time comes to 13 and 33 minutes, the message will not be issued.
I want to call the `alarmManager` in this way.
I want to have `calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 13)` and `calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, 33)` and to call `alarmManager` in this way.

EDIT 1:

I edited this code:

```
System.Timers.Timer t;
                if (t == null)
                {
                    t = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    //t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
                    //t.Elapsed += (sender, args) => FireTheMissiles();
                    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimeEvent);
                    t.Interval = 1000;
                    t.Enabled = true;
                }
                t.Start();
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
            flag = 3;
        }
        private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            h = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            m = DateTime.Now.Minute;

            RunOnUiThread(delegate
            {
                if (flag == 3)
                {
                    if (calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay) == h && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute) == m)
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "3 " + calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay).ToString() + " " + calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute).ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            });
        }
```

I asked my friends to implement this project on another application and see if a message would appear if the application did not open for 24 hours, but any message would not appear.

EDIT 2:

I used your code.
I also used the timer.
I saved the information like the time and date of installation in the database.
I wanted that the alarm appear by time and date.
But after several attempts, I did not receive any alert message.

```
private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RunOnUiThread(delegate
    {
        if (flag == 1)
        {
        }
        int h = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int m = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        dc = today.AddDays(1).Day;
        mc = today.AddDays(1).Month;
        yc = today.AddDays(1).Year;
        var data = mydb.Table<DatB>();
        var data1 = data.Where(x => x.DWSeen == dc).Where(x => x.MWSeen == mc).FirstOrDefault();
        if (flag == 3 && data1 != null && data1.RFSeen == 0)
        {
            startAlertAtParticularTime(data1.HourSeen, data1.MinuteSeen, "-1");
            if (calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay) == h && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute) == m && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth) == dc && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Month) == mc && calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.Year) == yc && data1.RFSeen == 0)
            {
                startAlertAtParticularTime(data1.HourSeen, data1.MinuteSeen, data1.RFSeen.ToString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

"-1" means that the alarm will not appear
"0" means the alarm will appear

```
namespace TestB
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    public class MyBR: BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            string dataSeenResult = intent.GetStringExtra("dataSeen");
            if ((MyApp.isActivityVisible() == "Stopped" || MyApp.isActivityVisible() == "Destroyed") && dataSeenResult == "0")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, MyApp.isActivityVisible().ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know what do you want to do, do you want to set a alarm with time 13:33 from your app?

Comment: Yes I want the application to alert at a specific time while it is closed

Comment: Have you checked my answer, any update?

Comment: I'm testing my program. I will announce.

Comment: @Grace Feng - MSFT  Hello. I did EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes I want the application to alert at a specific time while it is closed

Firstly you will need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the alarm notification from system. Then you can use `AlarmManager` to set alarm in your `OnPause` or `OnDestroy`:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
var pendingintent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myintent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
calendar.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 13);
cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, 33);
cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = this.GetSystemService(AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pendingintent);
```

For the `BroadcastReceiver` part, you may refer to Cheesebaron's answer in this case: [Xamarin AlarmManager Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460571/xamarin-alarmmanager-android).

Comment: Hello. I did EDIT 2.