# Run services in background every hour even if the app has been closed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to run a service to check the network status. I need to check this every hour, even if the app has been force closed form the recent app tray. I have created the service and it works on load and runs once. Not sure how to run it every hour and after its been closed.

Service

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace example.Services
{
    [Service(Label = "NetworkService")]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.example.NetworkService" })]
    public class NetworkService : Service
    {
    IBinder binder;

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {

        // start your service logic here
        string filename = "network.txt";
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);

        if(!File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Create(filePath);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
        bool isOnline = networkInfo.IsConnected;

        if(isOnline)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Connected");
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Not Connected");
        }
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            binder = new NetworkServiceBinder(this);
            return binder;
        }
    }

    public class NetworkServiceBinder : Binder
    {
        readonly NetworkService service;

        public NetworkServiceBinder(NetworkService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        public NetworkService GetNetworkService()
        {
        return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.NetworkService" />
```

MainActivity

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace whitesrecycling.Activities
{
    [Activity(Label = "HomeActivity")]
    public class HomeActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();

            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(Services.NotifcationService)));
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(Services.NetworkService)));
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar.Title = "Example";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `AlarmManager` then

Comment: Hi, have you tested my answer?

Comment: Hi I did, the AlarmManager seems to be working thank you

Comment: What is your target version? You need integrate some things. I hope my answer can give you a way.

Comment: API 19, i added in this ` Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver)); var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent); var alarmManager = GetSystemService(AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();
            alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime,0, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, pending);`

Comment: Api19, 4.4, you can only use `AlarmManager`  in your project.

Comment: So for 7.0 you'd say use JobScheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @pskink has said, you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), and you also can use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).

Here is the usage of [AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460571/xamarin-alarmmanager-android), and here is the use of [JobScheduler](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/JobScheduler/).

Some suggestions:

- If Api<19, please use `AlarmManager`.
- If Api>21, please use `JobScheduler`.

In Android, you can't keep your app alive always, because it will consume much power.