# How to implement an Android Service in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, service, xamarin.forms, android-service

I'm trying to periodically check with a web service if a new item has been added to a database. If there's a new item a listview that the user sees should be updated.
I'm using PCL and I have accomplish it creating a new Task with a timer inside. But this only works if the app is open. I want to do the same when the app is closed so the user gets a notification when a new item is added remotely.
I've been doing some research and I found andoid services, the info said that the service will continue, regardless of the app state, until you tell it to stop. But i haven't found many examples in how to implement it.

Here's the code that I had that works only when the app is opened:

```
 Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs), checkUpdates);
            });

  bool checkUpdates()
      {
        if (isOnline)
        {
            var lastUp= Application.Current.Properties["lastUpdate"] as string;

    //returns true if a new item is added
            if (service.newItem(DateTime.Parse(lastUp)))
            {
                var itm = service.getNewItem(DateTime.Parse(lastUp));

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                        notification.ShowNotification(itm.Title, 1000);
                        listView.Insert(0, itm);
                 }                        
                });                  
            }
            App.Current.Properties["lastUpdate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I'm trying to do the same with an Android service using dependency services, here's what I've got so far:

```
 public interface IService
    {
        void Start();
    }

  [Service]
    public class DependentService : Service, IService
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(DependentService));
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(intent);
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            // From shared code or in your PCL


            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the code that I had in the timer to the service, can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, you should probably look at the [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Have a look at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460571/xamarin-alarmmanager-android), where there's an example for one and maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) as well. The second one is Java but it might give you an idea of what you might deal with

EDIT:

You might also want to have a look at these Xamarin.Android documents around [Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/service-notifications) and [BroadcastReceivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers), to get better understanding with what you're dealing

Comment: No worries. Hope that it will help you a bit at least